# How do I allow a specific user to add users to Meteor.users?

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I have the following challenge.

I have a team manager user who is responsible for a list of users.
They need to add user details to other documents that these users belong to.
These users will not initially have an account on the site but they need to be there to be selected as linked to the main document.

How do I allow this team manager to create users with a limited amount of data 
e.g. 
Name 
Address
Phone#
etc..

These details would be used within the system to send e-mail etc. to these users.

Then at a later stage give the users the option of "Activating" the account?

I was thinking of creating a separate collection for user Profile/Details and then allowing this team manager the ability to create users and populate the users details.

I could then allow them once they have added all the users they want to in the system to send out a message that initiates a password reset for these users.

Is this a sane way of doing things and is there any security issues that I have not foreseen?

Thanks
Lance

Comment: I think you're on the right track. Have the Team Manager create "users" in a separate collection. When that user attempts to sign up, use a unique key to link the two and pull that information in during account creation to populate data in the users profile. I would use Accounts.onCreateUser() to catch the account creation and pull in that users data based on the unique key.

Comment: how about creating these users but using <a href="https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles">this package</a> to set rules to these users that are limited. then when they are ready, have the person with the admin role be able to switch their role to normal user .

Comment: @BrettMcLain This is exactly what I wanted to do so I will be investigating methods of creating the codes when we are ready to invite the team members to the party :-)

Comment: @sdybskiy I did not think of using a limited role from the get go.
I just have to figure out the best way for the Team Manager to create these users.

Comment: To use roles the accounts need to be created first, which requires a password. It is not recommended to create accounts with default or unhashed passwords.

Comment: @BrettMcLain true, I will have to think about it a bit more. Thanks